# How to call a Controller Action thats redirect to another action via Javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a devexpress button in my view wich only works with javascript.
So i need to call a Action via this click event.

My Script:

```
 function OnCommandExecuted(s, e) {
    if (e.item.name == "SendData") {           
        $.post("/Product/ExportData");
    }
 }
```

When i click on this button the Action /Product/ExportData executes but dont returns me nothing. My Actions:

```
 public ActionResult ExportData()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Test");
    }

    public ActionResult Test()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
    }
```

So, both the actions are executed but the sites dont change to the corresponding view. It stays on the original view where the button was clicked.

how can i change to the corresponding action view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AJAX call cannot make a browser redirect by default. Instead of Redirecting on the server, send the URL as a JSonResult and using client side JQuery catch that URL and make a redirect as shown below -

Let your controller action return Json as shown below -

```
    public ActionResult GetJson()
    {
        return new JsonResult() { Data = "http://www.google.com",JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
```

Then call this controller action from JQuery as shown below -

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function submitForm() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("GetJson")",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                window.location.href = data;
            },
            failure: function (errMsg) {
                alert(errMsg);
            }
        });
    }
</script>

<input type="button" value="Click" onclick="submitForm()" />
```

So when you click the button a POST operation to the controller action will be made and the return URL will be caught in Success function. Then using window.location.href, we make a browser redirect.

**EDIT**

One way to construct URL -

```
UrlHelper h = new UrlHelper(ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.RequestContext);
string str = h.Action("action", "controller", null);
return new JsonResult() { Data = str,JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
```

Alternatively at the same time you can use [Uri class in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but theres some method to construct the URL in the controller without especifing the string url? I mean, passing the action and controller the method makes the url and i can put parameters on it.